# Land-use optimisation where options can use one OR other land type to satisfy their requirements

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, pulp

I'm looking to solve a simple land-use optimisation problem to maximise the amount provided by each potential land-use.

Land is divided between Categories 1-3 (Cat1, Cat2, Cat3).
There are:

- 7m of Cat1 available
- 15m of Cat2 available
- 10m of Cat3 available

There are 2 options for land use (op1, op2)

- op1 must use 10m of Cat3 or above (Cat3 or Cat2 or Cat1) and 5m if Cat2 or above (Cat2 or Cat1)
- op2 must use 5m of Cat3 or above and 10m of Cat2 or above.

op1 provides 6 units while op2 provides 8 units.

I'm trying to solve this problem in pulp but the answer doesn't comply with the constraints. Can anyone help find what I'm doing wrong in my formulation, I'm new to Pulp and no idea why it's not working.

Defining variables and parameters:

```
land_uses = list(["op1","op2"])
provides = dict(zip(land_uses, [6,8]))
usage1 = dict(zip(land_uses, [10,5]))
usage2 = dict(zip(land_uses, [5,10]))  
cat1 = LpVariable.dicts("cat1", land_uses, lowBound = 0, cat = 'Integer')
cat2 = LpVariable.dicts("cat2", land_uses, lowBound = 0, cat = 'Integer')
cat3 = LpVariable.dicts("cat3", land_uses, lowBound = 0, cat = 'Integer')
land_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Land_use", land_uses, lowBound = 0, cat = 'Integer')
```

Defining problem and objective function:

```
simple = LpProblem("land_optimisation", LpMaximize)
simple += lpSum([provides[i] * land_vars[i] for i in land_vars])
```

Defining constraints:

```
simple += lpSum([(usage1[i]*land_vars[i]) - (cat1[i] + cat2[i] + cat3[i] ) for i in land_vars])  == 0
simple += lpSum([(usage2[i]*land_vars[i]) - (cat1[i] + cat2[i]) for i in land_vars])  == 0 
simple += lpSum([cat1[i] for i in land_vars]) <= 7
simple += lpSum([cat2[i] for i in land_vars]) <= 15
simple += lpSum([cat3[i] for i in land_vars]) <= 10
```

Solving and results:

```
simple.solve()
for v in simple.variables():
print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

Land_use_op1 = 2
Land_use_op2 = 1
cat1_op1 = 7
cat1_op2 = 0
cat2_op1 = 0
cat2_op2 = 13
cat3_op1 = 0
cat3_op2 = 0
```

It seems to say for option 1 for example, it only uses 7 Cat3 or above where it should use 20 (since there are 2 of op1 chosen). I have no idea if this is something that can even be done in pulp, but I can't think of any other way of expressing this! Really desperate for any help/pointers, I'm sure this should be easier than it feels. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I get different results: `Land_use_op1 = 2.0
Land_use_op2 = 1.0
cat1_op1 = 5.0
cat1_op2 = 0.0
cat2_op1 = 15.0
cat2_op2 = 0.0
cat3_op1 = 5.0
cat3_op2 = 0.0`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have written it out again as it is above in a new script and I get different results from before (probably the result of tinkering and not updating kernels - will edit my post) but they still aren't the same as yours. Also it's strange that yours says 1 of op2 but that op2 doesn't use any land...

Comment: Could the discrepancy be due to the solver used?

Comment: Do you think there are different solvers used? - Another question: What unit of _land_ measurement is _m_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to the site.

You have 2 things in your formulation that are causing you problems right now....  Let's cover that and then a working fix.

1. In your constraint:

```
simple += lpSum([(usage1[i]*land_vars[i]) - (cat1[i] + cat2[i] + cat3[i] ) for i in land_vars])  == 0
```

You are summing this across both uses at once, so you are getting a pooled result instead of what you want, which is "by EACH" use.  You should be putting that constraint inside of a for-loop and constructing one for each use individually.  That is further complicated by the next issue...

2. In your formulation, you are totaling assignments against 2 different requirements, and it isn't clear which requirement the commitment is against, so when you put in both of your constraints for (cat 1, 2, 3) and (cat 1, 2) it is possible for `cat1[i]` to count towards *both* of the requirements, which is clearly incorrect.

So you need a way to track the commitment of land to (1) a particular use and (2) against which of your two requirements to avoid this.  This can be done with a double-indexed variable (use, reqt).  I did that, and went 1 more step to roll up the different categories of land into the index (this is optional, but prevents you from writing separate constraints for each named variable).

So, 2 points from above:  You need to handle the "for each" constraints individually, which can be done w/ loops.  And due to fact that a commitment needs to be tracked against only 1 requirement, you should split that into an index.

Example:

```
from pulp import *

### DATA
cats = [1, 2, 3]  # categories of land
land_uses = ['op1', 'op2']
reqts = ['regular', 'premium']  # regular = cat 3+, premium = cat 2+
provides = dict(zip(land_uses, [6, 8]))
reqt_use = {    ('op1', 'regular') : 10,
                ('op1', 'premium') : 5,
                ('op2', 'regular') : 5,
                ('op2', 'premium') : 10}
# need some way to indicate which cats are tied to which reqt...
cat_pool = {    'regular' : [1, 2, 3],
                'premium' : [1, 2]}
avail = {   1 : 7,
            2 : 15,
            3 : 10}

### SETUP
# decision variable to commit x amount of "cat" land to "use" against "reqt"
x = LpVariable.dicts("commit", [(cat, use, reqt) 
    for cat in cats 
    for use in land_uses
    for reqt in reqts], 
    lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

# decision variable to count what is built
build = LpVariable.dicts("build", land_uses, lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

### OBJ

simple = LpProblem("land_optimisation", LpMaximize)
# collect value, subtract tiny penalty for committed land prevents extra
# commitments that don't credit a build
simple += lpSum([provides[i] * build[i] for i in land_uses]) - \
            lpSum(0.01*x[cat, use, reqt] for cat in cats for use in land_uses for reqt in reqts)

### CONSTRAINTS

# only use what is available in EACH category, across all uses and reqts
for cat in cats:
    simple += lpSum(x[cat, use, reqt] for use in land_uses for reqt in reqts) <= avail[cat]

# limit the build to what is committed, by individual requirement.
# This is a double "for each" ...uses and reqts
for use in land_uses:
    for reqt in reqts:
        simple += build[use]*reqt_use[use, reqt] <= lpSum(x[cat, use, reqt] for cat in cat_pool[reqt])

simple.solve()
for v in simple.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)
```

#### Yields

```
Result - Optimal solution found

Objective value:                15.70000000
Enumerated nodes:               0
Total iterations:               0
Time (CPU seconds):             0.00
Time (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

Option for printingOptions changed from normal to all
Total time (CPU seconds):       0.00   (Wallclock seconds):       0.00

build_op1 = 0.0
build_op2 = 2.0
commit_(1,_'op1',_'premium') = 0.0
commit_(1,_'op1',_'regular') = 0.0
commit_(1,_'op2',_'premium') = 7.0
commit_(1,_'op2',_'regular') = 0.0
commit_(2,_'op1',_'premium') = 0.0
commit_(2,_'op1',_'regular') = 0.0
commit_(2,_'op2',_'premium') = 13.0
commit_(2,_'op2',_'regular') = 0.0
commit_(3,_'op1',_'premium') = 0.0
commit_(3,_'op1',_'regular') = 0.0
commit_(3,_'op2',_'premium') = 0.0
commit_(3,_'op2',_'regular') = 10.0
[Finished in 175ms]
```

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome and for this amazing and thorough answer! I'm honestly a little gobsmacked someone took the time to answer my question! Thank you and all the best!